# FeedBack service from APNS (Apple push notification Server)

Tags: java, iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are using `Java` as the push notification provider for `APNS.I` am able to send the messages to the `APNS` but I have no idea as to how to get the feedback for the message.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feedback service has a binary interface similar to the interface used for sending push notifications. You access the production feedback service via `feedback.push.apple.com` on port **2196** and the development feedback service via `feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com` on port **2196**.

for reference [Updated Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html)

You can Use [javapns](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/) powerful and fine-tuned Java library for APNS,

[FeedbackBasicExample](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/FeedbackBasicExample)

**Note:** feedback service seems to only work on the production url.

Comment: @cmoran92 valid link to documentation documentation:https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH106-SW4