# IF DEVICE IS SWITHOFF then what will be the Action of APNS about notification

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

i want to know about APNS Services. i have tried lot related to apns feedback service but i am not geeting right result, i am using APNS services in ios application. now i want to know that , when i am shotdown the iphone and any one give notification in this application, thwn what will be action perform by te apns. please explain me.
    i want to know many more about feedback services and APNS Working.
  i have trying to learn about feebback services also.

please suggest me.
    thanks in Advance.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760923/feedback-service-from-apns-apple-push-notification-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APNS will post notification once your device is swittched ON in this case.